# BS 5 colapsar programaticamente

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

En las versiones anteriores de BS con jquery puedo ejecutar esto:

```
function changes() {
    $('#demostración').collapse('toggle');
}
```

para alternar mediante programación la vista collase de un elemento en BS5 no existe y un ejemplo de cómo hacer y ejecutar esto:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#how-it-works

Incluso en la pequeña documentación de javascript dice lo siguiente:

> Via JavaScript 
> **Enable** manually...

Entiendo que esto quiere decir que se le da o habilita a un ejemplo que puede ser colapsable... pero no se explica ni se indica como se dispara el efecto junto con la animación o sin la animación.

¿Alguien puede aclarar si esto ya no se puede hacer? Dado que tengo un div que al final de la carga y ejecución de un script sobre una entrada de tipo texto... muestra un div que estaba colapsado.

otra alternativa era antes usar show/hidden pero con el abandono de jquery... esto ya no se puede hacer programáticamente (sin botones o clic del usuario)

Estoy tratando de resolverlo con javascript vanilla y BS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitaba hacer una solución con javascript:

```
let div = document.querySelector('#results');
if (!div.classList.contains('collapse')) {
    div.classList.add('collapse', 'show');
} else {
    div.classList.remove('collapse', 'show');
}
```

temporalmente esto lo resuelbe implrementado add y remove de classlist; pero estoy bastante seguro de que no debería estar haciendo esto; si no es que BS ya incluye algo incorporado

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta:
Hay que obtener una instancia del elemento y luego usar la función `toggle()`

```
let div = document.querySelector('#collapseExample');
bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(div).toggle();
```

---

Un ejemplo con 5 botones:

```js
function colapsar_ArcanisGK507(){
  let div = document.querySelector('#collapseExample');
  if (!div.classList.contains('collapse')) {
    div.classList.add('collapse', 'show');
  } else {
    div.classList.remove('collapse', 'show');
  }
}

function colapsar_cambioclase(){
  let div = document.querySelector('#collapseExample');
  div.classList.toggle("show")
}

function colapsar()
{
   let div = document.querySelector('#collapseExample');
   bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(div).toggle();
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    1.- Collapse normal
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" onclick="colapsar_ArcanisGK507()">
   2.- Collapse método ArcanisGK507
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" onclick="colapsar_cambioclase()">
   3.- Collapse por cambio de clase
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" onclick="colapsar()">
   4.- Collapse usando BT API
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    bla bla bla bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>
```

Analizando cada caso:

**1.- Collapse normal:**
El de toda la vida, que no ocupa JS generado por el usuario.

**2.- Collapse método ArcanisGK507:** Este es el método que ArcanisGK507 ha publicado como respuesta. Y como se puede apreciar que no funciona al presionarlo por una segunda vez, esto porque se elimina la clase `collapse`

**3.- Collapse por cambio de clase:** Es la misma idea de la función anterior, pero ahora solo cambiando la clase `show` y usando la función [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).
Ahora si funciona, pero **el problema es que no se genera la animación**

**4.- Collapse usando BT API:**
Esta es la manera en que la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#methods) indica que se haga y es similar a como funcionan el resto de los componentes de Bootstrap, y es que simplemente se obtiene o sea crea una instancia del elemento y luego se ejecuta la función requerida, en este caso `toggle` (podría haber sido `show` o `hide` dada la necesidad)